# AppleScript does not display dialogs that contain Unicode characters

Tags: applescript

I use AppleScript's script editor. When I try to display `\u...` formatted characters in a dialog box as readable text, I don't succeed. What's the problem?

Here's what I tried:

```
set theTextItems to (do shell script "printf \"\\u82f9\\u679c\"")
display dialog theTextItems as text
```

The output of the dialog box that pops up is:

```
\u82f9\u679c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like OP is trying to parse JSON-encoded data using plain AppleScript. Don’t. Use JSON Helper app (available in AppStore) or `NSJSONSerialization` via the AppleScript-ObjC bridge. Those will process any character escapes for you.